# JavaScript - How set the width/position of a button in percentual?

Tags: html, mobile, rotation

I need to set the position/size of elements in page in porcent for when the mobile rotate ...

I have tried:

```
frame.width = 30%;
button.width = 50%;
```

Answer (score 1):

Expert Chris Coyier offers excellent advice on how to classify device orientation based on media query.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
```

[Here is the article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

This is a key topic in the emerging field of Responsive Web Design.

Here is a simple example:

```
<style>
    /* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : landscape) {
    /* Styles */
         .frame{width : 30%;}
         .button{width : 50%;}
    }
</style>
```

Or, include within a separate css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./responsiveness.css">
```

Good Question. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, happy to explain... This is CSS. It can be added within a <style></style> tag. Or in a linked CSS file, which is generally the preference. I will edit response to include example.

Comment: @DevMobile - I recommend that you read up on and become more familiar with *CSS* and *JavaScript* individually.

Comment: Putting this code in JS will mean requiring maintenance to that code as devices change. It does boil down to the same solution of setting the css as context changes, but css has better long-term maintenance. This is because all responsive code can be located in a single separate file.

Comment: (Note: I mentioned he should read up on JavaScript because the "what I've tried" section of the question looks like broken JS code, and the question is tagged JavaScript.)

Comment: The styles were adjusted to class handle '.', and css syntax.